# How To Update Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 10?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

I installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 10 back in November 2014. As far as I remember, I got an over-the-air update at some point. I have been away a lot and have only just come back to my Nexus 10, now to find that:

1) there is no system update available, which seems very strange considering all the work that has been done since the Ubuntu phones started being released (I have a EQ 4.5 and have regularly been reviving updates for it!), and

2) app updates don't "stick" - i.e., app updates are shown to download and install but when I tap out of the updates screen, and then back into the updates screen, all updates are shown as requiring to be installed again!

Tech specs:
- OS: Ubuntu 15.04 (r2)

Output of `system-image-cli -i`:

```
current build number: 2
channel: devel
alias: ubuntu-touch/vivid
last update: 2016-10-24 02:48:14 
version version: 2 
version ubuntu: 20150413 
version device: 20150210 
version custom: 20150413
```

Comment: You should include the output of `system-image-cli -i` in your question, so people can better provide an answer.

Comment: Same problem exactly on Nexus 7
Even though I attempt to update, the system-image-cli shows a last update from 2015-04 (six months old)
current build number: 2
channel: devel
alias: ubuntu-touch/vivid
version version: 2

Comment: Thanks @dobey. This is the output from system-image-cli -i:
`code`
current build number: 2
channel: devel
alias: ubuntu-touch/vivid
last update: 2016-10-24 02:48:14
version version: 2
version ubuntu: 20150413
version device: 20150210
version custom: 20150413`code`

Any suggestions much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Support for the Nexus 10 was deprecated some time ago. If you want a current image to run on your device, you need to flash your device using the [UBports](https://devices.ubports.com/#/) server:

`ubuntu-device-flash --server https://system-image.ubports.com touch --channel ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed`

This will flash the current rc-proposed channel image onto your device.